# Why does aspect wants return type int?

Tags: eclipse, aspectj

The following aspect give me a "This method must return a result type of int"

```
package CH.ifa.draw.framework;

public aspect Trace {

     after() returning (ConnectionFigure figure): call(*.new(..)) {
         System.out.println("test");
     }
}
```

I'm expecting void as the result type.

**Update**

I expect that this pointcut is called for every creation a class that implement de ConnectionFigure interface

**Update 2**

```
package CH.ifa.draw.framework;

public aspect Trace {

     after(): call(ConnectionFigure+.new(..)) {
         System.out.println("trace creation figure");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your aspect advice is incorrect, or at least incomplete.  The `returning (ConnectionFigure figure)` should be given you an error since the parameter is unbound in the pointcut expression.  Try removiong that component and seeing if it works for you.

Comment: after cleaning the project, it's working fine. Take a look at my edit